# Bootstrap Carousel Lazy Load

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm trying to have the bootstrap Carousel lazy load. It seems like this should be straight forward, but I'm not even getting any errors here to troubleshoot. JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bigCarousel').on("slid", function() {
        // load the next image after the current one slid
        var $nextImage = $('.active.item', this).next('.item').find('img');
        $nextImage.attr('src', $nextImage.data('lazy-load-src'));
    });

</script>
```

And then html:

```
<div id="bigCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
        <img src="assets/bigimage1.jpg" class="img-big">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-lazy-load-src="assets/menu-header2.jpg" class="img-big">
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

No JS errors in firebug or anything else I can figure out, but my images just aren't loading. Probably something stupidly simple here...

Comment: FYI: the event on bootstrap 3 is now `slid.bs.carousel` eg. `$('#myCarousel').on("slid.bs.carousel", function() { ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [lazy load not work in bootstrap carousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675968/lazy-load-not-work-in-bootstrap-carousel)

Answer (score 20):

The simplest solution would be:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide lazy-load" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active"><img src="image1.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img data-src="image2.jpg"></div>
  <div class="item"><img data-src="image3.jpg"></div>
</div>
<!-- controls -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.carousel.lazy-load').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var image = $(e.relatedTarget).find('img[data-src]');
        image.attr('src', image.data('src'));
        image.removeAttr('data-src');
    });
});
</script>
```

That's it!

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is the $ in your nextImage var.  Unless you are trying to preload 1 slide early, I would also switch to a "slide" event instead of "slid" event.  Also, you should probably account for scrolling forwards AND backwards.  This includes checks for looping around from first photo to last photo and vice versa.

```
$('#myCarousel').on("slide", function(e) {

        //SCROLLING LEFT
        var prevItem = $('.active.item', this).prev('.item');

        //Account for looping to LAST image
        if(!prevItem.length){
            prevItem = $('.active.item', this).siblings(":last");
        }

        //Get image selector
        prevImage = prevItem.find('img');

        //Remove class to not load again - probably unnecessary
        if(prevImage.hasClass('lazy-load')){
            prevImage.removeClass('lazy-load');
            prevImage.attr('src', prevImage.data('lazy-load-src'));
        }

        //SCROLLING RIGHT
        var nextItem = $('.active.item', this).next('.item');

        //Account for looping to FIRST image
        if(!nextItem.length){
            nextItem = $('.active.item', this).siblings(":first");
        }

        //Get image selector
        nextImage = nextItem.find('img');

        //Remove class to not load again - probably unnecessary
        if(nextImage.hasClass('lazy-load')){
            nextImage.removeClass('lazy-load');
            nextImage.attr('src', nextImage.data('lazy-load-src'));
        }

    });
```

Comment: I like this method of pre-loading and would recommend it, but you will only benefit from more than 3 slides.

Comment: This will break on the prev if there is another element after the last item (like the <a> from the example). 
Fix might be replacing the sibling selector above with ``sibling(".item:last-of-type")``

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution, you just need to set img-url/path in temporary image attribute,
see code below img has attribute **url**

```
<div class="item">
 <img url="./image/1.jpg" src="">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
   <h4>title</h4>
   <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

when event **slid**, set value : **src = url**

```
$('document').ready(function() {     
        $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
            var url = $('.item.active').find("img").attr('url'); 
            $('.item.active').find("img").attr("src", url); //set value : src = url
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function() {
    var $nextImage = $('.active.item', this).next('.item').find('img');
    $nextImage.attr('src', $nextImage.data('data-lazy-load-src'));
});
```

You are loading as `$nextImage.data('lazy-load-src')` but it should be `$nextImage.data('data-lazy-load-src')` according to scripting.

Comment: for me it's not working with the 'slid' event. If use with 'slide.bs.carousel' work's fine. Thx @Sameera Thilakasiri