# lazy load not work in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I create carousel using bootstrap 3 like this :

HTML :

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="http://rivathemes.net/html/envor/img/posts/3.jpg" class="img-big">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img data-lazy-load-src="http://rivathemes.net/html/envor/img/posts/4.jpg" class="img-big">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-controls">
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left fa-lg"></i></a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-lg"></i></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

and add this code for add `img` lazy load.

JS :

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid', function () {
    var $nextImage = $('.active.item', this).next('.item').find('img');
    $nextImage.attr('src', $nextImage.data('lazy-load-src'));
});
```

But, This not work for me!? can do fix this ?

Important Q: can i add image preloader for lazy load?!

DEMO : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BoWw/51muqdLf/)

Comment: Change the event `slid` into `slide.bs.carousel`, see http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events

Comment: you may check how this works http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-full-slider/

Comment: @Ahmad: your mean is : insert image into inline style?! `style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');"`

Comment: Add `data-interval="0"` to the `<div id="myCarousel">` to disable this. But please take a look at the documentation, it's all in there

Comment: @ckuijjer: you right! i fix with : `$('.carousel').carousel({interval: 5000})`. can i add preloader this is important.

Comment: What's a preloader for lazy load? This sounds like a contradiction.

Comment: @T-M I am not sure it works az lazy load, just as a sample to make your slider run!

Comment: @ckuijjer: add preloader before image load complete in each slide.

Comment: @ckuijjer: i add caption and carousel not work !! http://jsfiddle.net/BoWw/51muqdLf/2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ys4je40u/

1. add `lazy-load` class to item object
2. use `slide.bs.carousel` event

**CSS:**

```
.lazy-load {
    background: url("http://www.mozart.it/images/preloader.gif") center center no-repeat;
}
```

**JQ:**

```
var cHeight = 0;

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $nextImage = null;

    $activeItem = $('.active.item', this);

    if (e.direction == 'left'){
        $nextImage = $activeItem.next('.item').find('img');
    } else {
        if ($activeItem.index() == 0){
            $nextImage = $('img:last', $activeItem.parent());
        } else {
            $nextImage = $activeItem.prev('.item').find('img');
        }
    }

    // prevents the slide decrease in height
    if (cHeight == 0) {
       cHeight = $(this).height();
       $activeItem.next('.item').height(cHeight);
    }

    // prevents the loaded image if it is already loaded
    var src = $nextImage.data('lazy-load-src');

    if (typeof src !== "undefined" && src != "") {
       $nextImage.attr('src', src)
       $nextImage.data('lazy-load-src', '');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

The [answer by dm4web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27677524/2978652) does not account for skipping slides by directly clicking the carousel indicators. This version correctly loads an image regardless of how you slide to it, using Bootstrap's `event.relatedTarget` (the item being slid into place, see [the official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events)). Try running the snippet below and clicking on the indicators to switch several slides ahead.

```js
var cHeight = 0;

$('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {

  var $nextImage = $(e.relatedTarget).find('img');

  $activeItem = $('.active.item', this);

  // prevents the slide decrease in height
  if (cHeight == 0) {
    cHeight = $(this).height();
    $activeItem.next('.item').height(cHeight);
  }

  // prevents the loaded image if it is already loaded
  var src = $nextImage.data('lazy-load-src');

  if (typeof src !== "undefined" && src != "") {
    $nextImage.attr('src', src)
    $nextImage.data('lazy-load-src', '');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/5000x1000">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-lazy-load-src="http://placehold.it/5001x1000">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-lazy-load-src="http://placehold.it/5002x1000">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-lazy-load-src="http://placehold.it/5003x1000">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img data-lazy-load-src="http://placehold.it/5004x1000">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple images in your slide, you have to use this :

```js
var cHeight = 0;

$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $nextImage = null;

    $activeItem = $('.active.item', this);

    if (e.direction == 'left'){
        $nextImage = $activeItem.next('.item').find('img');
    } else {
        if ($activeItem.index() == 0){
            $nextImage = $('img:last', $activeItem.parent());
        } else {
            $nextImage = $activeItem.prev('.item').find('img');
        }
    }

    // prevents the slide decrease in height
    if (cHeight == 0) {
       cHeight = $(this).height();
       $activeItem.next('.item').height(cHeight);
    }

    // => Changes here ! 
    // prevents the loaded images if it is already loaded
    $nextImage.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            src = $this.data('original');

        if (typeof src !== "undefined" && src != "") {
           $this.attr('src', src)
           $this.data('original', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Created this "kinda generic" solution some months ago and had no issues so far...

```
var $ajaxCarousel = $('.carousel-ajax');

if ($ajaxCarousel.length > 0) {
    $ajaxCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $upcomingImage = $(e.relatedTarget).find('img');
        if (typeof $upcomingImage.attr('src') === 'undefined') {
            $upcomingImage.attr('src', $upcomingImage.data('src'));
        }
    });
    // preload first image
    $ajaxCarousel.each(function() {
        var $firstImage = $(this).find('[data-slide-number=0]').find('img');

        $firstImage.attr('src', $firstImage.data('src'));
    });
}
```

All you have to do in HTML is add "carousel-ajax" class to your existing carousel and prepend "data-" in front of your img's src tags:

```
<img data-src="..." />
```