# Lazy load not working with bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

I have a very large website which was being slowed by having large amounts of images in carousels. To decrease load time I have used lazy load to prevent high-quality images from loading with the page. I have a click function which triggers lazy-load once the user has left the home page and replaces the dummy images with HD ones. The issue is when the user scrolls to the part of the page where the images should display only the first and sometimes second images are replaced. The rest stay as dummy images.

```
<div class="item active">
    <img src="./img/tinyBlur.jpg" data-2x-1="./img/design7.png" class="carosuelImg lazyload-2x loading-lazy hidden">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="./img/tinyBlur.jpg" data-2x-1="./img/design8.png" class="carosuelImg lazyload-2x loading-lazy hidden">
</div>

$(".blocks").click(
    function(){
    $('.lazyload-2x').each(function() {
        $(this).Lazy({
            attribute: 'data-2x-1',
            threshold: 0
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lazy load not work in bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675968/lazy-load-not-work-in-bootstrap-carousel)

Comment: First things first, are you getting any JS errors in the console?